# How do you account for receiver sensitivity in tranceiver half wave dipoles?

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance, impedance-matching, dipole

if you are to design 2 halfwave dipoles, both can transmit to each other using 3 watts and have receiver sensitivity of -80dbm (a picowatt). Suppose they are 800m and have same height from ground. How do you design such a system, assuming all impedance matchings and efficiencies are perfect?

traditional equations are P = 1/2*Resistance(73-ohm)*I and E = (η*I)/(2*pi*r). I could put P = 3 watts in the first equation to solve for I, then put I in the 2nd equation to get the field at that radius offset. But then I wouldn't have used the -80dbm, the equations don't account for both powers. How do designers account for sensitivity?

Comment: -80dBm is 10 picowatts not 1 picowatt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "traditional" way of estimating the attenuation between antennas is by using the free-space equations derived by Harold Friis. Then make some adjustments to account for antenna gain and fade-margin (real earth scenarios).

> Link Loss (dB) = 32.4 + 20\$log_{10}\$(F) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

where F is MHz and d is distance between the two antennas (in kilometres).

If you are using 2.45 GHz and require 0.8 km to be covered, the link loss is: -

```
32.4 dB + 67.8 dB + (-1.9 dB) = 98.3 dB
```

If you transmit 3 watts (34.8 dBm) you will receive -63.5 dBm

But, this is for isotropic antennas and of course these transmit power in all directions. For a quarter wave monopole at each end the link loss lowers by about 4 dB hence you will receive about 60 dBm.

Fade margin is a bit of a hand waving estimate but a simple approach is to assume that you might expect the power received to be down by 20 dB is a reasonable first guess. This leaves you at -80dBm.

---

The 32.4 dB part comes from mopping up this formula: -

[image]

Pr is received power, Pt is transmitted power. Gt and Gr are antenna gains and for isotropic antennas are assumed to be unity. Convertion of \$\lambda\$ to MHz and R to kilometres is part of the mopping up as is the 4\$\pi\$.

Basically 32.4 = 20log\$_{10}(\dfrac{40\pi}{3})\$

Comment: where does the 32.4 come from, i have seen it multiple times?

Comment: See edit section above. The added formula is the non-log version.

Comment: Thankyou very very much Mr Randy, i was also wondering about how Radiation resistance affects radiation. like 73ohm, 50 ohm, and 90-ohm are the matched radiation resistance of an antenna, how will they affect the wave assuming its the same frequency.

Comment: Radiation resistance of a vacuum is about 377 ohms from memory. This gets transformed to an electrical resistance depending on antenna type.  Does that make sense?